# React Native Gifted Chat Rendering Issues

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I have been pulling my hair out the last two days and nights trying to figure out why the Gifted Chat package behaves the way it does once the user clicks on the text input box.

If you head to Gifted Chat's GitHub (https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) and install and run their package, this is the performance out of the box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WehYP.jpg. The main issue here is that the input seems to "sling-shot" when the user clicks on it, meaning that it dips below the keyboard and then re-surfaces. This effect is more prominent in the actual application in which I am using this package (the entire input bar will dip below the keyboard), but it's noticeable even when compared to the standard KeyboardAvoidingView behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8o2N.jpg. How can Gifted Chat be modified to perform like the latter example?

Given that it ships out of the box like this, I was hoping someone has dealt with this situation in the past and could offer a helping hand - thanks a million.